# Eu posso ter vários thead e tbody dentro de uma única table no HTML5?

Tags: html5

Queria fazer uma tabela dessa, mas só posso ter uma tag table e queria saber se é semânticamente certo colocar vários thead e tbody dentro de uma só table.
[image: Foto da tabela descrita]

Comment: como você sabe que tem tbody e thead nessa imagem exemplo, se tem o código? eu realmente não sei a semântica correta, mas, eu acho (achismo) que só pode ter um para cada `<table>`

Comment: embora tenha layout de tabela e semanticamente seja correto usar uma tag table aqui, isso não te limita, podes fazer isso com div por exemplo

Answer (score 2):

Sintaticamente é provável que qualquer coisa seja possível, mas semanticamente é permitido zero ou um `thead` e zero ou vários `tbody`.

```js
console.log(document.querySelectorAll("table tbody").length)
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

```html
<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Coluna 1</th>
    <th>Coluna 2</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Valor 1</td>
    <td>Valor 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Valor 3</td>
    <td>Valor 4</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Valor A</td>
    <td>Valor B</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Valor C</td>
    <td>Valor D</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Citando a MDN ([fonte](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table))

> **Conteúdo permitido** (nesta ordem)
>
> - um elemento `<caption>` opcional ,
> - zero ou mais elementos `<colgroup>`,
> - **um elemento `<thead>` opcional**,
> - qualquer um dos seguintes:
>
>   - **zero ou mais elementos `<tbody>`**
>   - um ou mais elementos `<tr>`
> - um elemento `<tfoot>` opcional

Comment: O pior que eu não vi nenhum exemplo mostrando isso!

Comment: @novic Não viu exemplo onde?

Comment: `tbody`: vários em uma tabela, eu to procurando também eu não achei nenhum que demostre isso, nesse que é a sua resposta eu vi mesmo, mas, não vi nada exemplificando.

Answer (score 2):

Resposta curta, sim pode, inclusive vc pode ter uma table inteira dentro da outra, o que é chamado de ***Nesting Tables*** e o código ficaria tipo isso

```html
  <table border="1" style="text-align: center; width: 300px">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="2">thead</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">row</th>
        <td>item row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">

          <table border="1" style="width: 100%">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">col</th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>item col</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>

        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="2">tfoot</th>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
```

A maioria dos elementos da tabela são opcionais, menos o `<tbody>`, inclusive no Chrome vc pode fazer um teste simples, crie uma tabela e não use o `<tbody>` e ao inspecionar a tabela vc vai ver que o próprio Browser vai colocar a tag para vc :)

Resumindo vc deve ter pelo menos 1 `tbody`, ou quantos quiser. Inclusive o próprio validadorde HTML oficial da W3C não acusa erro ao usar múltiplos `tbody`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sobre a semana da tabela a Mozilla tem uma documentação exclusiva para isso https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Tables/Advanced

Inclusive vc vai ver que ele usa alguns atributos específicos dos elementos da tabela para dar semântica ao código como `scope`, `rowgroup`, `colgroup` e `id + header` em conjunto como no exemplo abaixo

```
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th id="purchase">Purchase</th>
    <th id="location">Location</th>
    <th id="date">Date</th>
    <th id="evaluation">Evaluation</th>
    <th id="cost">Cost (€)</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
  <th id="haircut">Haircut</th>
  <td headers="location haircut">Hairdresser</td>
  <td headers="date haircut">12/09</td>
  <td headers="evaluation haircut">Great idea</td>
  <td headers="cost haircut">30</td>
</tr>

  ...

</tbody>
```

Comment: Pode se colocar 2 `tbody` na mesma tabela? já viu exemplos?

Comment: componentes eu já vi isso que você colocou na sua resposta, agora eu quero saber a pelo que está na pergunta se uma tabela pode ter dois ou mais tbody e porquer mais do que um? por exemplo na resposta abaixo visualmente não mudou nada!

Comment: Sim realmente hugo,

Comment: Eu preciso fazer a tabela da foto, se você vir ela você vai perceber que o cabeçalho dela se repete várias vezes, como eu posso repetir vários deles se eu só posso usar 0 ou 1 thead?

Comment: @LucasJava é como falei na primeira parte da minha resposta, vc vai ter uma tabela, dentro dela vários tbody, dentro de cada tbody outra tabela com thead/body/footer... Ou então vc usa a estrutura com TH e se quiser dar semântica usa o scope e os  id/headers. Lembre-se, o `thead` é opcional, ele nem precisa existir na tabela!