# Centralizar colunas de uma tabela com Bootstrap

Tags: css

**Não tenho muita facilidade em .css, por isso recorri aqui. Segue abaixo o código e detalhes.**

```
 <div class="container">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="colunm1">
                        <a href="#create">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary bg-success text-white border-white">
                                <svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-plus-square" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M14 1H2a1 1 0 0 0-1 1v12a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h12a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V2a1 1 0 0 0-1-1zM2 0a2 2 0 0 0-2 2v12a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h12a2 2 0 0 0 2-2V2a2 2 0 0 0-2-2H2z"/>
                                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v3h3a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-3v3a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-3h-3a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1h3v-3A.5.5 0 0 1 8 4z"/>
                                </svg>
                                Adicionar Item
                            </button>
                        </a>
                    </th>
                    <th class="col2">Produto</th>
                    <th class="col3">Ações</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr th:each="item : ${items}">
                    <td th:text="'#' + ${item.id}">#1</td>
                    <td th:text="${item.name}">Produto1</td>
                    <th>
                        
                        <a href="#read">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary bg-info text-white border-white">
                                <svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-arrows-angle-expand" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M5.828 10.172a.5.5 0 0 0-.707 0l-4.096 4.096V11.5a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0v3.975a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5H4.5a.5.5 0 0 0 0-1H1.732l4.096-4.096a.5.5 0 0 0 0-.707zm4.344-4.344a.5.5 0 0 0 .707 0l4.096-4.096V4.5a.5.5 0 1 0 1 0V.525a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5H11.5a.5.5 0 0 0 0 1h2.768l-4.096 4.096a.5.5 0 0 0 0 .707z"/>
                                </svg>
                                Infos       
                            </button>
                        </a>
                        <a href="#update">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary bg-warning text-white border-white">
                                <svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-pencil-square" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                    <path d="M15.502 1.94a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .706L14.459 3.69l-2-2L13.502.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .707 0l1.293 1.293zm-1.75 2.456l-2-2L4.939 9.21a.5.5 0 0 0-.121.196l-.805 2.414a.25.25 0 0 0 .316.316l2.414-.805a.5.5 0 0 0 .196-.12l6.813-6.814z"/>
                                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M1 13.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 2.5 15h11a1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1.5-1.5v-6a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0v6a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5h-11a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5v-11a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5H9a.5.5 0 0 0 0-1H2.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1 2.5v11z"/>
                                </svg>
                                Modificar
                            </button>
                        </a>
                        <a href="#delete" >
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary bg-danger text-white border-white">
                                <svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-trash" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                    <path d="M5.5 5.5A.5.5 0 0 1 6 6v6a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V6a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5zm2.5 0a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v6a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V6a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5zm3 .5a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0v6a.5.5 0 0 0 1 0V6z"></path>
                                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M14.5 3a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H13v9a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H5a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V4h-.5a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V2a1 1 0 0 1 1-1H6a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2a1 1 0 0 1 1 1h3.5a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v1zM4.118 4L4 4.059V13a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h6a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V4.059L11.882 4H4.118zM2.5 3V2h11v1h-11z"></path>
                                </svg>
                                Excluir
                            </button>
                        </a>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

**Estou tentando:**

- deixar a tabela em si centralizada
- usar 60% do espaço da tabela para a coluna do meio
- usar 20% do espaço da tabela para as colunas laterais
- deixar a coluna da esquerda centralizada

**O que já tentei sem sucesso:**

- usar classes do bootstrap com divisões de coluna usados em div
- diminuir o tamanho da tabela
- criar um arquivo .css para estilizar manualmente as margens e endentação do texto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeiramente classe `col` é para ser filho direto de `row`, e nada tem a ver com a tabela. Se vc viu na documentação `scopre="col"` isso é referente a acessibilidade e não ao Grid do Bootstrap (aqui tem alguma coisa sobra a semântica HTML da tabela [Eu posso ter vários thead e tbody dentro de uma única table no HTML5?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/478375/eu-posso-ter-v%c3%a1rios-thead-e-tbody-dentro-de-uma-%c3%banica-table-no-html5/478388#478388)).

Outra coisa, um `td` ou `th` já tem um `display` nativo, que é relativo ai pai... resumindo, o pai é uma `<table>`, que possui `display: table`, e os filhos são `display: table-row`, `display: table-cell`, etc, então **não use display: flex** em th, tr, td, thead, etc!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código da tabela acima, fiz tudo com `style` para vc ver onde foi aplicado cada coisa, e e coloquei um `border` só para vc ver a distribuição das coisas

```css
th, td {
border: 1px solid black;
}
html {
height: 100%;
}
body {
height: 100%;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<div class="container">
  <table class="table mb-0">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th style="width: 20%; text-align: center;">
          <a href="#create">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary bg-success text-white border-white">
              <svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-plus-square" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M14 1H2a1 1 0 0 0-1 1v12a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h12a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V2a1 1 0 0 0-1-1zM2 0a2 2 0 0 0-2 2v12a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h12a2 2 0 0 0 2-2V2a2 2 0 0 0-2-2H2z" />
                <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v3h3a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-3v3a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-3h-3a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1h3v-3A.5.5 0 0 1 8 4z" />
              </svg>
              Adicionar Item
            </button>
          </a>
        </th>
        <th style="width: 60%; text-align: center;">Produto</th>
        <th style="width: 20%; text-align: center;">Ações</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr th:each="item : ${items}">
        <td style="text-align: center;" th:text="'#' + ${item.id}">#1</td>
        <td th:text="${item.name}">Produto1</td>
        <th>

          <a href="#read">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary bg-info text-white border-white">
              <svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-arrows-angle-expand" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M5.828 10.172a.5.5 0 0 0-.707 0l-4.096 4.096V11.5a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0v3.975a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5H4.5a.5.5 0 0 0 0-1H1.732l4.096-4.096a.5.5 0 0 0 0-.707zm4.344-4.344a.5.5 0 0 0 .707 0l4.096-4.096V4.5a.5.5 0 1 0 1 0V.525a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5H11.5a.5.5 0 0 0 0 1h2.768l-4.096 4.096a.5.5 0 0 0 0 .707z" />
              </svg>
              Infos
            </button>
          </a>
          <a href="#update">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary bg-warning text-white border-white">
              <svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-pencil-square" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <path d="M15.502 1.94a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .706L14.459 3.69l-2-2L13.502.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .707 0l1.293 1.293zm-1.75 2.456l-2-2L4.939 9.21a.5.5 0 0 0-.121.196l-.805 2.414a.25.25 0 0 0 .316.316l2.414-.805a.5.5 0 0 0 .196-.12l6.813-6.814z" />
                <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M1 13.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 2.5 15h11a1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1.5-1.5v-6a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0v6a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5h-11a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5v-11a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5H9a.5.5 0 0 0 0-1H2.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1 2.5v11z" />
              </svg>
              Modificar
            </button>
          </a>
          <a href="#delete">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary bg-danger text-white border-white">
              <svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-trash" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <path d="M5.5 5.5A.5.5 0 0 1 6 6v6a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V6a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5zm2.5 0a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v6a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V6a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5zm3 .5a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0v6a.5.5 0 0 0 1 0V6z"></path>
                <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M14.5 3a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H13v9a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H5a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V4h-.5a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V2a1 1 0 0 1 1-1H6a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2a1 1 0 0 1 1 1h3.5a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v1zM4.118 4L4 4.059V13a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h6a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V4.059L11.882 4H4.118zM2.5 3V2h11v1h-11z"></path>
              </svg>
              Excluir
            </button>
          </a>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```